# how to uninstall emacs from command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, uninstall, emacs

I have ubuntu 12.04

I installed emacs using below commands.

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install emacs
```

Then, as expected, I could find emacs while searching in dash.

Next I wanted to uninstall emacs, so I did:

```
$ apt-get remove emacs
```

But still I can search emacs in dash. Also I am able to open emacs and use it.

However when I check below command.

```
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$ dpkg --status emacs
Package `emacs' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
sps@sps-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

It says emacs not installed. But how am I able to use emacs?

To correctly ask , "How to uninstall it ?"

I mean how do I get everything erased. I dont want any of these - source code (if any), or binary executable, or anything related to emacs -  in my system, which was added when I did `apt-get install emacs`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emacs` is actually a virtual package, [provided by](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/emacs) `emacs23-lucid` or `emacs23-nox`. It's these that should be removed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove emacs23-lucid emacs23-nox
```

The `--auto-remove` removes any packages which were installed to fill a dependency, but are no longer needed. In this case, it will remove packages like `emacs23-bin-common`.

Comment: I tried the command you told but I am getting this error `E: Command line option --autoremove is not understood` . Also I tried by removing the `--autoremove` option. But still I get below error `E: Unable to locate package emacs24-lucid` `E: Unable to locate package emacs24-nox` . Could you please check ?

Comment: @1Byn I made two mistakes, the option is `--auto-remove` with a hyphen, and the packages are numbered 23, since you're on 12.04 (which I didn't notice).

Comment: Working now. No emacs in dash either !!. Thanks. Also can you tell this "package" is a source code or executable binary ? I mean when you say a "package" in general ?

Comment: @1Byn Unless someone explicitly says "source package", "package" usually means "binary package" - but it doesn't have to be executable or even binary (such as documentation packages, software in languages like Python, packages containing common files).

Comment: An additional bit of information: If you're on Ubuntu 14.04, the package is emacs24, no suffix.

Comment: Just for info.: `sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove emacs` worked fine for me.