# Ubuntu 18.04 automatically downgrades my emacs 26 compiled from source to the respository version emacs 25

Tags: emacs

I had a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Emacs 26 compiled from source. However I notice somehow the system always installs Emacs 47.0 which is Emacs 25.2.2 from the official Ubuntu repository. This completely destroys my Emacs 26 installation and I have absolutely no idea why this should/could happy, i.e. no warning or reminder. Has anyone else experienced this similar issue? Or could anyone point me to where to start to diagnose the automatic installation occurs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `sudo apt purge emacs` the system will think `emacs` is not installed (and doesn't need to be upgraded). Then install your `emacs`.

Comment: I followed [this ask ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604733/how-to-uninstall-emacs-from-command-line?rq=1) and [this blog post](https://arp242.net/weblog/uninstalling_emacs_with_apt-get-_lessons_in_interface_design) to completely remove the automatically installed emacs 25. `locate emacs25` and `updatedb`shows no emacs25 related files remaining in the system. I am trying your suggestions now and see if it's going to work.

Comment: Here's your warning or reminder: Apt does not know about non-deb software, does not care, and will happily overwrite it. If you use non-deb software on your system, use /usr/share/local or /opt to avoid file conflicts with debs.

Comment: @user535733 Please excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean non-deb software? I complied emacs 26 from source, generated the .deb package with `checkinstall' and installed with `dpkg -i`. Furthermore, why should Apt overwrite emacs 26 if I did not do any `apt upgrade` at all? So far, I have hold the emacs 26 with `dpkg --set-selections`. It looks like the problem has been solved after several reboot, but to be honest, I am still confused why this overwrite should happen.

Comment: Lot of good information there that needs to be in the original question, not buried among comments. You are still asking us to be rather psychic, and there are several possibilities: Perhaps you used an unwise version number, maybe you ran an apt command not realizing what it would do, or maybe you didn't use apt-pinning or apt-marking to hold the current version, etc. Lots of possible traps for the unwary.

Comment: @user535733 My apologize for the original post and thanks for your reply. I will edit the post later with all the findings when I get a bit more time. Like I said earlier, I seem to fix the problem by holding emacs 26 with `dpkg` (or perhaps same with your `apt-marking`) but I am still puzzled and do not believe it should happen without user's authentication.

Comment: @user535733 `apt-cache policy emacs` shows the "controversial"  emacs 47.0 (emacs 25.2.2) in the repository as a candidate to my source-compiled emacs 26.1-1. And the former has a priority of 500 compared to 100 of the later in the version table. Not sure if that provides some insight.